# Dynamically generate classes name using SCSS

Tags: sass

I'm trying to generate some dynamic class names.
I need an SCSS function that will dynamically create all possible CSS classes combinations
starting with 'availability-; and followed by numbers from 1 to 5.
It has to have at least one 1 number.

Examples:

availability-1
availability-1-2
availability-1-3
availability-1-4
availability-1-5
availability-1-2-3
availability-1-2-4
availability-1-2-5
availability-1-3-4
[...]
availability-1-2-3-4-5

So far I have this:

```
@function generateAvailabilityClasses($numbers...) {
  $combinations: ();

  @for $i from 1 through length($numbers) {
    $combinations: append($combinations, $numbers[$i]);

    @for $j from $i + 1 through length($numbers) {
      $combinations: append($combinations, join($combinations, '-'), $numbers[$j]);
    }
  }

  @return $combinations;
}

$availabilityClasses: generateAvailabilityClasses(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

But the compiler says `SassError: $separator: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) [2] is not a string.`

I'm trying to generate some dynamic class names.
I need an SCSS function that will dynamically create all possible CSS classes combinations
starting with 'availability-; and followed by numbers from 1 to 5.
It has to have at least one 1 number.

Examples:

availability-1
availability-1-2
availability-1-3
availability-1-4
availability-1-5
availability-1-2-3
availability-1-2-4
availability-1-2-5
availability-1-3-4
[...]
availability-1-2-3-4-5

So far I have this:

```
@function generateAvailabilityClasses($numbers...) {
  $combinations: ();

  @for $i from 1 through length($numbers) {
    $combinations: append($combinations, $numbers[$i]);

    @for $j from $i + 1 through length($numbers) {
      $combinations: append($combinations, join($combinations, '-'), $numbers[$j]);
    }
  }

  @return $combinations;
}

$availabilityClasses: generateAvailabilityClasses(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

But the compiler says `SassError: $separator: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) [2] is not a string.`

Comment: You'll need a recursive function to generate all combinations. Change `$numbers[$i])` to `nth($numbers, $i)`, and your append/join syntax is wrong, `join($combinations, '-') + nth($numbers, $j - 1)` is closer, but you'll still need a recursive function, or 5 nested loops, to generate all combinations

Comment: not sure what's you're looking for here